# Pin the last item to the right in a horizontal navigation menu using CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a horizontal nav that will have a variable amount of links. For this particular example, I have 3, as seen below:

[image]

I want the first 2 to remain where they are and the 3rd one to be positioned all the way to the right. The only way I've been able to figure out how to do this is by setting a width on the links, like this: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(130px, 1fr));` and then adding the following to the element that I want at the end: `grid-column-end: -1;`

That would work, but I don't want all the links to be the same width. I want the widths to be set to `auto`, but then I don't have an implicit grid that spans the full width, and therefore can't seem to put that 3rd link at the very far right of the nav bar. Is there a relatively easy way I can accomplish this with CSS Grid? If not, how could I do this with Flexbox? I want to avoid using floats and absolute positioning.

Here is the CSS I'm currently using:

```
ul.nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I've tried many times to get this working in a nice way. I usually end up just using nested grids (one grid for stuff on the left, one grid for stuff on the right and a third grid to position them) and moving on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Grid, you need a rule that says: *"set all columns to `auto` regardless of number, but the last column to `1fr`"*. Then set the last grid item to `margin-left: auto`.

However, I've seen nothing in the [current Grid spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) (level 1) that allows you to target the last column in an unknown number of columns.

To my knowledge, this can't be done with `grid-template-columns`, `grid-auto-columns` or a combination thereof.

However, with flexbox the layout is simple. Just set the last item to `margin-left: auto`.

---

### Grid Layout

This is how it would work for a definite number of columns.

Set the first two columns to `auto`, which uses the content length.

Set the third column to `1fr`, which:

1. consumes all free space on the line, and
2. pins the first two columns to the left.

Then use an `auto` margin to pin the third link (a grid item) to the right (within the space of the third column).

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
}

a:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* demo styles */
nav { background-color: lightgray ; border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px 0; }
a   { background-color: lightgreen; border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
  <a>Link 3</a>
</nav>
```

### Flex Layout

This is how it would work for a definite or indefinite number of flex items.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

a:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/* demo styles */
nav { background-color: lightgray ; border: 1px solid gray;  padding: 5px 0; }
a   { background-color: lightgreen; border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>Link 1</a>
  <a>Link 2</a>
  <a>Link 3</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'll probably go with the Flex route. The Grid solution would work if I always had a set number of links, but it will vary depending on the user. Is there not a good solution for that using Grid?